# Indefined index php array

Tags: php

Why am I getting undefined. That is most silly code I've posted but I have no PHP programmer to ask, so here I am.

```
 $resultados = ["nome" => "magalu", "idade" => 200];



 echo $resultados[0]["idade"];
```

Let's go

```
 $resultados = ["nome" => "diego", "idade" => 200];
```

I am creating a variable with index 0 equal to an array that has two keys "nome", "idade".

```
echo $resultados[0]["idade"];
```

Now I am accessing that index and displaying the value of the "idade" key.

Comment: There is no index 0 based on your array. The only indexes you have are 'nome
' and 'idade'.

Comment: What do you mean "*I am creating a variable with index 0 equal to an array*"?

Comment: I wrote this question in rage.But what can I do my brain grew with typed languages and will always be cauch.

Comment: `$resultados = [ ["nome" => "diego", "idade" => 200] ];` would allow you to `echo $resultados[0]["idade"];` or `echo $resultados[0]['nome'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With what you have you have two indexes.
'nome' and 'idade'.

```
$resultados = ["nome" => "diego", "idade" => 200];
```

If you want 0 then you can add these to an array like this and then you can use 0 index.

```
$resultados = [["nome" => "diego", "idade" => 200]];
echo $resultados[0]["idade"];
```

Comment: Yes, "resultados" is not an array.  I needed $resultados[] = ["nome".....

Comment: Doing this once $resultados[] = is the same as my example. :)

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is

```
echo $resultados["idade"];
```

It should be

```
$array[$key]
```

In your case keys are `nome` and `idade`

If you want to display the entire array you can use `print_r` or `var_dump`.
For example `print_r($resultados)` or `var_dump($resultados)`.